Title: Issue with Insert Statement Generation for @ElementCollection Mapping in JPA
I'm encountering difficulties with generating insert statements for an @ElementCollection mapping in my JPA entity. Here's a summary of my setup:
I have an entity class CustomMeal that extends another entity class Meal. In CustomMeal, I have a Map<MenuItem, Integer> field named mealItems, which is annotated with @ElementCollection.
Here's a simplified version of my CustomMeal entity:
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class CustomMeal extends Meal {

    // Other fields and annotations omitted for brevity

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "custom_meal_menu_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "menu_item_id")
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private final Map<MenuItem, Integer> mealItems;

    // Constructor, getters, setters, and other methods omitted for brevity
}

and also my MenuItem entity:
public class MenuItem {

    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "UUID")
    @Id
    private  UUID id;
        // Other fields and annotations omitted for brevity


The problem is that sql  insert statements aren't generated for the "custom_meal_menu_items" table when a CustomMeal entity is persisted. The  sql statements generated are:
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        meals
        (date_added, vendor_name, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        custom_meal
        (client_id, id) 
    values
        (?, ?)

I'm seeking advice on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
